# Width wrong when using display table-cell and floated element in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

It appears that FireFox (17.0.1) is calculating the width incorrectly when using a display of table-cell and a floated element where it sets the parent width and doesn't include the width of the floated element in the parent width.  This appears to work in Chrome, IE8, IE9, and IE10.

```
   <div style="position:absolute">
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="option">
            <div>
                <div class="right">right text</div>
                <div class="cell">content item 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
             <div>
                 <div class="right">right</div>
                 <div class="cell">content</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .right {float:right;}
    .cell
    {
        display:table-cell;
        height:30px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        border:1px solid green
    }
</style>​
```

If possible, I'm looking for a CSS only fix since this is an existing.  Some of the HTML might not make sense, but I've eliminated 90% to make the example cleaner.

I have noticed a couple of table-cell bugs where a display:table, display:table-row is required on some parent element... but I couldn't find a combination that works.

Also, I'm trying to avoid hard-coding a width.

Comment: Is adding `float:left` to `.cell` an option?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because it removes the benefits of table-cell, specifically, vertical alignment. I updated the sample to put back in the vertical alignment.

Comment: Can you change the order: put `.cell` before `.right`?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov what are you trying to say that would do?

Comment: @ZackT. You can give `.right` `display:table-cell`, they will stand next to each other.

Comment: Doesn't `display:inline` vertically puts things in the middle?

Comment: Note that per spec the behavior of this HTML+CSS is undefined, so there is no "wrong" or "right" here...

Comment: If you reference a spec, please include specific links so we can educate ourselves.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make your life easier by removing `float: right;`
and adding `display: table-row;` on the container div:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/u9RU4/1/

I tested this in FF-Chrome-IE9 and IE8- and Safari for you.
......that is unless you need the float....

Comment: Close, but float:right right aligns the content.  I updated the HTML so the second option has less text to highlight the layout.

Comment: like this then?:
`.right {
    display: table-cell;
    float: right;
}`